# How do I force premailer to send a plaintext email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I'm using the premailer gem to facilitate sending emails. One specific type of email, I always need to send plaintext.

How can I force premailer to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the .html.erb template and it automatically sends only plaintext emails!